# Is there a keyboard shortcut to stop the execution of a program without restarting PC on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

If I am not able to control the mouse, is there a way to stop a program? For example, say I were to execute this code:

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(
    HINSTANCE /*hInstance*/, 
    HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/, 
    PSTR /*pCmdLine*/, 
    int /*nCmdShow*/)
{
    INPUT inputs[3] = {};

    inputs[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    inputs[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
    inputs[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    inputs[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    inputs[2].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    inputs[2].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

    while (1)
    {
        inputs[0].mi.dx = (rand() % 1000) - 500;
        inputs[0].mi.dy = (rand() % 1000) - 500;
        SendInput(3, inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This would make the mouse cursor jump around and click randomly. If I were to execute this, would my only option be to restart the PC?

Comment: If the program is windowless, then start the task manager to end the program.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes, but the cursor would be uncontrollable. I need a way to do this without utilizing the mouse at all.

Comment: @SetupWizard You can start the task manager with Windows-R, and then you can control the task manager with the tab and arrow keys and the special context menu key (sorry don't know it's real name) next to the right ctrl key. No mouse necessary.

Comment: @john If the mouse is clicking randomly, this is not an option, because you lose the focus of task manager.

Comment: @VLL OK, I missed that part. Perhaps the code could be altered to listen for some key, and quit if it is pressed.

Comment: @john I suppose I could use 'RegisterHotKey()' to implement a kill-switch.

Comment: I missed the effect of the mouse clicks ;) 
Create a batch file to kill your program, make a shortcut to it and on the properties of the shortcut (right-click -> shortcut) there is the possibility to assign a hotkey to the shortcut. Worth a try (https://tweaks.com/windows/39559/kill-processes-from-command-prompt/)

Comment: If another program has focus (e.g. task manager) it can't steal the mouse from this program

Comment: It is possible to start the task manager and navigate to select a process and end/terminate it (if you have access to do so) using only the keyboard.  No reliance on mouse.   CTRL-ALT-DELETE then use cursor keys to select "Task Manager", hit enter to start it, then (since task manager will have focus) use cursor keys to select process to terminate, and ALT-E (for end) to terminate the process you chose.   It's not pretty, and relies on you knowing what keys to hit, but it works with no reliance on mouse.

Answer (score 0):

some tips are follow by me. On a personal computer with the Microsoft Windows operating system, **Control**+**Alt**+**Delete**() is the combination of the Ctrl key, the Alt key and Del key that a user can press at the same time to **terminate an application task** or to reboot the operating system. some times your pc is also shutdown if you are press again and again.